# C#/XAML Error No overload for 'button_Click' matches delegate 'Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventHandler'

Tags: c#, xaml, event-handling, windows-phone, controls

I am trying to switch between two previously defined styles in App.xaml for multiple buttons each time a button gets clicked. I tried a generic event handler but it will display the error **No overload for 'button_Click' matches delegate 'Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventHandler'**. I believe it has to do with the signature but can't quite fix it. Here's the method implemented in MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button)sender;
        if (button.Style != myButtonStyle)
            button.Style = myButtonStylePressed;
        else
            button.Style = myButtonStyle;
    }
```

And this is how it is implemented in MainPage.xaml in one button sample.

```
<Button Name="Row5Col4"
            Grid.Row ="5"
            Grid.Column ="4"
            Margin="10, 10, 10, 10"
            Height="10"
            Width="10" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            BorderThickness="0"
            Style="{StaticResource myButtonStyle}"
            Click="button_Click"
            >
    </Button>
```

IMPORTANT: some people have recommended using MouseClick instead of Click, however this won't work since it is a WP application. I appreciate you stopping by.

The line that, according to Visual Studio causes the bug is this one
    **Click="button_Click"**

Comment: `button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` ..  Then it should work :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Button's Click event doesn't have a parameter type of EventArgs.According to [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) , it has to be RoutedEventArgs

So your code must be :

```
public void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    if (button.Style != myButtonStyle)
        button.Style = myButtonStylePressed;
    else
        button.Style = myButtonStyle;
}
```